# Как добавить значения в виде словаря, не заменяя прошлое значение?

Tags: python, словари

Проблема состоит в том что я не понимаю как нормально создать вложенный словарь. Значений несколько под одним ключом, но при работе функции значения перекрывают друг друга и остается только один словарь под ключом. Данные берутся из списка словарей где каждый словарь это параметры и оценки студента.

UPD: Пример входных данных

```
students = [
    {'Фамилия': "Иванов", 'Имя': 'Иван', 'Отчество': 'Иванович', 'Год рождения': 2003, 'Курс': 1, 'Группа': '219-2',
     'Оценки': {'ООП': 4, 'БД': 3, 'Экология': 5, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 4}},
    {'Фамилия': "Петров", 'Имя': 'Петр', 'Отчество': 'Петрович', 'Год рождения': 2001, 'Курс': 1, 'Группа': '219-1',
     'Оценки': {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 1, 'Химия': 5, 'История': 4}},
    {'Фамилия': "Денисов", 'Имя': 'Денис', 'Отчество': 'Денисович', 'birth_year': 2001, 'Курс': 1,
     'Группа': '219-2',
     'Оценки': {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 5, 'Экология': 5, 'Химия': 5, 'История': 5}},
    {'Фамилия': "Алексеев", 'Имя': 'Алексей', 'Отчество': 'Алексеевич', 'Год рождения': 2002, 'Курс': 2,
     'Группа': '219-1',
     'Оценки': {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 1, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 3}},
    {'Фамилия': "Сергеев", 'Имя': 'Сергей', 'Отчество': 'Сергеевич', 'Год рождения': 2002, 'Курс': 3,
     'Группа': '219-2',
     'Оценки': {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 4, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 1}}
]
```

Функция

```
def func(students):
    unqile = set([d['Группа'] for d in students])
    dict_3 = {}
    for x in unqile:
        for i in [d['Оценки'] for d in students]:
            for el in students:
                if el['Группа'] == x:
                    dict_3[x] =(i)
    return dict_3
```

На выходе:

```
{'219-2': {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 4, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 1}, '219-1': {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 4, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 1}}
```

А необходимо :

```
{'219-2': {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 4, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 1}, {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 5, 'Экология': 5, 'Химия': 5, 'История': 5},{'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 4, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 1}
'219-1': {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 4, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 1},{'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 1, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 3}}
```

Comment: а что надо получить на выходе-то? Покажи пример входных данных и того, что хочется на выходе.

Comment: А что если хранить под ключом не словарь, а список словарей и добавлять в него необходимые данные?

Comment: Пример входных данных добавил и то что нужно получить

Comment: пример выходных данных - синтаксически неверный. Данные в таком виде получить невозможно. Но можете сделать значением список, и добавлять туда словари.

Comment: так там же должен быть массив `{'219-2': [{}, {}, {}]}` а не просто `{'219-2': {}, {}, {}}` — такого типа данных нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если провести небольшой рефакторинг, можно обойтись только одним циклом без лишних действий это будет быстрее:

```
def get_groups_marks(students):
    result = {}
    for student in students:
        group = student['Группа']
        marks = student['Оценки']
        if (group in result): 
            result[group].append(marks)             
        else: 
            result[group] = [marks]
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

В словарь нельзя добавить значение уже существующему ключу без удаления предыдущего значение. Один ключ - одно значение. Это закон! Но к счастью для вас значением может быть список, а списке может быть много значений. Этим мы и воспользуемся, заодно убрав все ненужные циклы:

```
def func(students):
    unqile = set([d['Группа'] for d in students])
    dict_3 = {x:[] for x in unqile} # пустой словарь с ключами из названий групп
    for student in students:
        dict_3[student['Группа']].append(student['Оценки'])
    return dict_3
```

На выходе получается словарь, в котором значениями являются списки

```
{
    '219-2': [{'ООП': 4, 'БД': 3, 'Экология': 5, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 4},
              {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 5, 'Экология': 5, 'Химия': 5, 'История': 5},
              {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 4, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 1}],
    '219-1': [{'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 1, 'Химия': 5, 'История': 4},
              {'ООП': 3, 'БД': 2, 'Экология': 1, 'Химия': 2, 'История': 3}]
}
```